# javascript having issue with indexOf

Tags: javascript, html

So i have a html page with a guess my word game. but when i enter my first if statement with the variable `FinalGuess` for the `indexOf` it breaks, where as where i use `SecretWord` the page works but the function doesnt. any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Guessing Game</title>
<script type="text/javascript" >
/* <![CDATA[ */
var SecretWord = "compaq";
var GuessInput = document.forms[0].Guess.text;
var FinalGuess = GuessInput.toLowerCase();

var firstLetter = false;
var b = false;
var c = false;
var d = false;
var e = false;
var f = false;

function checkLetter() {

if (SecretWord.indexOf('c') >= 0) {
firstLetter == true;    
}
/*
if (userInput.indexOf('o') >= 0) {
b == true;  
}
if (userInput.indexOf('m') >= 0) {
c == true;  
}
if (userInput.indexOf('p') >= 0) {
d == true;  
}
if (userInput.indexOf('a') >= 0) {
e == true;  
}
if (userInput.indexOf('q') >= 0) {
d == true;  
}
*/  
if (firstLetter == false) {
var letter1 = "*";
} else {
var letter1 = "c";
}
if (b == false) {
var letter2 = "*";
} else {
var letter2 = "o";
}

if (c == false) {
var letter3 = "*";
} else {
var letter3 = "m";
}

if (d == false) {
var letter4 = "*";
} else {
var letter4 = "p";
}

if (e == false) {
var letter5 = "*";
} else {
var letter5 = "a";
}

if (f == false) {
var letter6 = "*";
} else {
var letter6 = "q";
}

var string = letter1 + letter2 + letter3 + letter4 + letter5 + letter6;

document.forms[0].word.value = string;
document.forms[0].Guess.value = "";
document.forms[0].Guess.focus;
alert(GuessInput);
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>

<body onload="checkLetter();">

<form action="" >
Guess the word
<input type="text" name="word" id="word" /><br />
Enter text here
<input type="text" name="Guess" maxlength="1" />
<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="checkLetter();" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok so i moved my variables to inside my function and it works now but i can seem to get the first indexOf to be true

Comment: you have to check the answer bellow, if the answer help you vote it up, if the answer is really what you looking for mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to replace :

```
firstLetter == true;
```

By :

```
firstLetter = true;
```

We use `==` for comparison, but when you want just to assign value use `=`.